# JavaFX controller injection does not work

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have two `fxml` files. I connect them with an `include` statement:

The "main" `fxml`file looks like that:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
// ...

<BorderPane prefHeight="962" prefWidth="1280" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MyMainController">
    <center>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.63" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <items>
                <fx:include source="AnotherFile.fxml" />
                // ...
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </center>
    <top>
        // ...
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

And the second one (= "AnotherFile.fxml") like that:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
// ...

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.15" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <items>
        // ...
        <Label fx:id="oneOfMyLabels" text="myText" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    </items>
</SplitPane>
```

Now, I am using injections in the "main"-controller `application.MyMainController`:

```
@FXML
private Label oneOfMyLabels;
```

If I run the controller I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception, respectively a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` one. In debugging mode I found out, that the injected `Label` is `null`!

Now, my question:
Can't reach the `MyMainController` from the "main fxml file" the components of the included fxml file?? Do I have to use an own controller on each fxml file, if it is included or not?!

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a different controller for each FXML file, and the `fx:id`-annotated elements of each file will be injected into the *corresponding* controller instance.

When you have included FXML files, you can inject the controller for the included file into the controller for the including file, by setting an `fx:id` attribute on the `fx:include` element:

"main" fxml file:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
// ...

<BorderPane prefHeight="962" prefWidth="1280" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MyMainController">
    <center>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.63" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <items>
                <fx:include fx:id="another" source="AnotherFile.fxml" />
                // ...
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </center>
    <top>
        // ...
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

and in the "main controller":

```
public class MyMainController {

    @FXML
    private AnotherController anotherController ;

    // ...
}
```

(the rule being that the field name is the value of the `fx:id` attribute with `"Controller"` appended). Here `AnotherController` is the controller class for `AnotherFile.fxml`.

Now you can, for example, expose the *data* you need to access in the "included controller":

```
public class AnotherController {

    @FXML
    private Label oneOfMyLabels ;

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return oneOfMyLabels.textProperty();
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then your main controller can do things like

```
anotherController.setText(...);
```

which will of course update the label. This preserves encapsulation, so that if you choose to use another control instead of a label, those changes do not have to propagate outside of the immediate controller.

Comment: One should remember that the root element of the included fxml file has to contain an own fx:controller attribut!

Comment: Is there a possibility to inject the `MyMainController` into the `AnotherController`? I need to invoke a method in the main controller out of the sub controller...