# Javafx Injected Controller is null

Tags: javafx

When I try to use the controller I injected into my main controller, I always get a Nullpointer Exception (widgetlinebelowtableController is null). I have seen this answer, but did not help: [JavaFX controller injection does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849277/javafx-controller-injection-does-not-work/32849444#32849444)

injected fxml:

```
    <HBox fx:id="widgetLineBelowTable" maxWidth="Infinity" spacing="5.0"   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.widgets.WidgetLineBelowTableController">
        <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
        </padding>
        <Label fx:id="warningLabel" text="Overflow"/>
   </HBox>
```

The controller for this fxml:

```
public class WidgetLineBelowTableController
    {
    @FXML
    Label warningLabel;

    public void setColor(int r, int g, int b) {
        warningLabel.setTextFill(Color.rgb(r,g,b));
    }

}
```

My main fxml:

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" stylesheets="/sample/style.css" fx:controller="sample.mainController">
    <fx:include source="/sample/menubar/MenuBar.fxml"/>
    <TabPane>

        <tabs>
            <Tab closable="false" text="FirstTab">
                <VBox>
                    <TitledPane collapsible="false">
                        <text>Results</text>
                        <fx:include source="table/Table.fxml"/>
                    </TitledPane>
                    <fx:include fx:id="widgetlinebelowtable" source="widgets/WidgetLineBelowTable.fxml" />
                </VBox>
            </Tab>
            <Tab closable="false" text="SecondTab">

            </Tab>
        </tabs>
    </TabPane>
</VBox>
```

The main controller:

```
import sample.widgets.WidgetLineBelowTableController;

public class mainController {

    @FXML
    private WidgetLineBelowTableController widgetlinebelowtableController;

    public mainController() {
        widgetlinebelowtableController.setColor(255,0,0);
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the injected field in the constructor, which obviously won't work (as the `FXMLLoader` cannot inject anything until the controller has been created, i.e. after the constructor executes).

Move the code to the `initialize()` method:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private WidgetLineBelowTableController widgetlinebelowtableController;

    public void initialize() {
        widgetlinebelowtableController.setColor(255,0,0);
    }

}
```

Also, please follow standard [naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)