# JavaFX - Components are null when initializing Controller

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, scenebuilder, jcomponent

## Main class :

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../layouts/main_window.fxml"));
primaryStage.setTitle("IMGManager");
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
primaryStage.show();
```

## FXML :

```
<VBox id="navigation" stylesheets="@../../css/center_panels.css" 
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
      fx:controller="controllers.NavigationController">

  <!-- ... -->

  <!-- List -->
  <AnchorPane prefHeight="1500.0" prefWidth="492.0">
      <children>
          <ListView id="directories-list" 
                    fx:id="navigationList" 
                    prefHeight="500.0" ... />
      </children>
  </AnchorPane>

</VBox>
```

## Controller : NavigationController

```
public class NavigationController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private ListView<String> navigationList;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        // Get Home Directory
        FileSystemView fsw = ...

        // Updates the information displayed in the Navigation panel.
        if (navigationList != null)
        {
            updateNavigationDisplay();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Hi, so the problems I have is :

> **1. )**
>
> Whenever I try to link a JavaFX component and a Controller variable, neither the Scene Builder nor Intellij makes the "connection" between the fx:id(s) and the variables in my Controllers.
>
> I always get the nullPointerError in the initialization of my Controller, but I found a (troublesome) workaround : `if (navigationList != null)`.
>
> I noticed that my initialization method fires twice. Once with null components and the second time (magic), components are detected. So by adding `if (navigationList != null)`, I don't get any errors on the first initialization and on the second I do cool stuffs.
>
> **2. )**
>
> I am unable to access a component located in another FXML file then the one linked with the Controller : nullPointer.
>
> ex:
>
> Controller1 <--linked with this, works well (on second init...) --> FXML1.fxml
>
> Controller1 -- trying to access components in --> FXML2.fxml ( fails miserably)
>
> ## EDIT:
>
> By "trying to access components in another fxml file", I mean with a mouse click or something like that -> And surely Not during the initialization, as some fxml files are not loaded yet.

I searched a lot for answers and lost a couple of hours on this. Most of the time, smilar cases were solved by correcting some small misspells, or missing @FXML tags or by adding a proper implementation of the Intializable interface, etc.

In my case, I really don't get it. Hopefully it's just a misspell or some small bugs.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1 : have you added given FXML directly in main_window.fxml or you have included this FXML in main_window.fxml?

Problem 2 : To access components located in another fxml through your controller of first fxml please refer this link :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgubWgheboI

I was facing same problem.:)

Comment: **Problem 1 :** The given FXML is indeed included.

**Problem 2 :** I watched the video a couple of times and what is diffenrent in my code is :

**a.)** I implemented the Initializable interface (so I guess the way proposed in the video to initializes the controllers is an alternative).

**b.)** It said that it is important for an included file to have **it's fx:id** set to it's corresponding fxml file name. I don't understand why, but I updated it in my fxml files and nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. To communicate between FXML files, you need a controller that can access Both (or multiple) FXML files via their include **fx:id**. So when designing the application, I have to group FXML files that needs to communicate between them under a same controller (a controller that access their controllers...[exemple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849277/javafx-controller-injection-does-not-work)). Is that right? I'm currently restructuring my application to try it out, won't be long. Meanwhile, what did you want to say about my **Problem 1** (didn't found a solution yet)

Answer (score 1):

Try use **fx:id=** instead of **id=** in fxml file. This solution works to me.